# How to train HAAR Classifier from 3d model in OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I am trying to train a HAAR Cascade for car detection from a Drone.
Because of the viewing angle of the drone, I need to detect the car from many angles, So I need to train the classifier for that.
I have many 3d car models of the cars I want to detect, Can I use them to train the classifier instead of getting images from the internet ?

The car may be not moving, so I can't use motion as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

there are many questions here. 
First, to train for many angles seems to be not really optimal for me, maybe you could check some more simple approaches like in this paper about car detection
https://www.tnt.uni-hannover.de/papers/data/977/scia2013_baumann.pdf

Second, yes, you can train on synthetic data, but there will be no noise as in real life and your classifier could be much less effective finally on real data. But usually to generate synthetic DB is fast, so why not to try.

Comment: thx for your reply, is their any thing in OpenCV related to the paper you mentioned?
I was thinking about template matching, feature matching or Cascade matching

Comment: @MohamedEl-Saka I've just found your idea already realized on gitHub : Vehicle Detection by Haar Cascades with OpenCV   https://github.com/andrewssobral/vehicle_detection_haarcascades

Comment: I found this paper discussing the issue
https://brage.bibsys.no/xmlui/bitstream/handle/11250/2418432/14189_FULLTEXT.pdf